# getJSON if checkbox is checked then uncheck

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, checkbox, getjson

I got a function getBrandUrl() which fires getProducts().

If a checkbox is checked and the function is fired (for the second time, on a checked checkbox) the checkbox needs to be unchecked. So I can build the GET request without the value of that checkbox to filter out products by brand.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="35890" onclick="javascript:getBrandUrl('35890');">
<a href="javascript:getBrandUrl('35890');" title="blabla" alt="blabla">blabla</a>
```

Clicking the a[href] (blabla) for the first time? then the checkbox needs to be checked and the GET request can be formatted. So if another checkbox or a[href] is clicked it appends to the URL and when it's clicked for the second time it needs to be removed.

```
function getBrandUrl(value)
        {
            getProducts("<?=$filterUrl?>", value, 'brand[]');
        }

function getProducts(url, value, type)
        {

            if($('input[type="checkbox"][value="' + value + '"]').is(':checked')) {
                $(this).attr('checked', 'false');
            } else {
                $(this).attr('checked', 'true');
            }

            var checked = '';
            $('input[name="' + type + '"]:checked').each(function() {
                checked += '&' + type + '=' + this.value;
            });

            $.getJSON(url + checked + "&json=true", function(data) {
                $('#productList').html('');

                $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                    var product = formatProductHTML(val.ID, val.PRICE, val.TITLE, val.LINK);

                    $(product).appendTo('#productList');
                });
            });
        }
```

The problem is that when I click for the first time it will be uncheck right away so it won't be in the formatted GET request.

Any idea's how to solve this problem or does anyone know what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Why not just uncheck it after your JSON processes...? If you're reloading the page based on which boxes are checked, just destroy the DOM, ie: $('#productList').empty(); and re-add items depending on the checked boxes.

Comment: I just have one function "getBrandUrl" which will be fired every time you click the checkbox or the link a[href] next to it. So the problem is that the checkbox is getting unchecked if it fired for the first time, even if I place the code after my getJSON.

Comment: So instead of using a string, use an object or an array and a function to create your URL. That way, you have much more control over removing pieces of it than trying to splice your string.

Comment: That's an option, but it still gets me stuck at the point that my checkbox is getting unchecked right away when im clicking the link. If the checkbox with the value is checked it gets unchecked. So it is getting unchecked becouse I just clicked on the link that is checking the checkbox. But how can I check if the checkbox was checked before. I need to format the GET request based on the checked values but you can click on the links aswell to check them.

Comment: Order of operations? Just change it around so the request handles the checked boxes unchecking AFTER its done with the data you need, ie [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zan62cgy/). If this doesn't help I don't know if I can help further, as I'm very confused exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Tried that already. Got some filter checkboxes with links next to it. If i click on a link it needs to check the checkbox. Onclick the checkbox fires the same function. If that checkbox is checked already (by clicking on the link earlier) the checkbox needs to be unchecked. Usually when you click on a checkbox it unchecks itself, but it needs to be also controlled by the link next to it. With every active checkbox i'm formatting the GET request for the results. Problem is when clicking the link next to the checkbox it is unchecking the checkbox becouse of the code you placed after the getJSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget all the checkbox JavaScript.

When you click on a label linked to the checkox it will automaticly check the checkbox linked to it, wich fires the javascript funtion..

```
<input type="checkbox" id="35890" name="brand[]" value="35890" onclick="javascript:getBrandUrl('35890');">
<label for="35890">blabla</label>
```

And you don't have to do any check or create a link to check a checkbox..